# Python List filled with duplicates

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, duplicates

Here is the code.

```
x=0
result=[]
for n in range(1,5):
    x=x+n;
    for i in range(1,10):
        if x%i==0:
            result.append(i)       
            print(x,result)
```

Here I have generated triangular numbers.I want to find the divisors of each triangular number.but when I execute the code I am getting the following output.

```
1 [1]
3 [1, 1]
3 [1, 1, 3]
6 [1, 1, 3, 1]
6 [1, 1, 3, 1, 2]
6 [1, 1, 3, 1, 2, 3]
6 [1, 1, 3, 1, 2, 3, 6]
10 [1, 1, 3, 1, 2, 3, 6, 1]
10 [1, 1, 3, 1, 2, 3, 6, 1, 2]
10 [1, 1, 3, 1, 2, 3, 6, 1, 2, 5]
```

Also same triangular number is repeated for several times.So I need an output looks like,

```
1 [1]
3 [1, 3]
6 [1, 2, 3, 6]
10 [1, 2, 5]
```

How can I get the output like this?thank you.

Comment: You don't clear `x` and `result` as you go along, not sure if that's the way you're trying to achieve your goal but perhaps resetting it at some point would help.

Answer (score 3):

You are appending to the same `result` list inside the loop. You should create a new `result` list in the outer loop. And your print statement is wrongly indented. Move it outside the inner loop.

Your code should be:

```
x=0
for n in range(1,5):
    x=x+n;
    result = []
    for i in range(1,10):
        if x%i==0:
            result.append(i)       
    print(x,result)
```

**Output:**

```
1 [1]
3 [1, 3]
6 [1, 2, 3, 6]
10 [1, 2, 5]
```

Comment: I think the print should be IN the for but not in the if

Comment: @Ofek.T.. No, because then it will print the list mutiple time for the same `x`.

Answer (score 0):

To find divisor of a number you can use this function

```
def divisors(n):
    divisors=[]
    for i in range(1,int(n**0.5)+1):
        if n%i == 0:
            divisors.extend((i,n/i))
    return list(set(divisors))
```

if you find a number i which can divide a number n, both n and n/i become divisors..
The only problem will be with perfect square numbers where its root will be added twice(if i become root of n, n/i and i are equal and both will be added to list).
It is solved by `set()` function.